# Is it safe for keeping my laptop plugged in while updating to Windows 10 via windows update

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, dell-xps, charging

I have Dell XPS-L502X(Early 2011) Laptop with 6-cell battery and currently I'm **Downloading Windows 10 via Windows Update** from Windows 7 Home Premium-64 bit.

But my Internet Speed is just **512 kbps** which will take nearly **17 hrs to download 3 GB file**. And I can't always plug-unplug my laptop for charging, so for this time I want to keep my laptop plugged in for most waited upgrade.

**Will being Plugged in for 17 hour be safe for my laptop or Battery or adapter?**

Comment: You might want to poke around in your Control Panel to see whether your system has a smart battery charging mode [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KKjLC.png).  It causes the machine to periodically "pretend" to be unplugged, let the battery run down to about a 50% charge, and then recharge it.  But, as far as I know, Ulincsys is right, and this is not critical for short periods (i.e., less than two weeks).

Comment: Should i use Option Turn Off Battery Charging-which will stop the battery from charging until the next time the system reboots.

Comment: That sounds dangerous.  How it that different from just unplugging?  What happens if the battery gets completely discharged?  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...  BTW, another obvious (not so obvious) question is: What happens if the battery completely discharges, and the machine powers down, while it's downloading?  It may be possible to resume the download where you left off.  (Or you might need to start over.)

Comment: Thanks for support. My system automatically disabled charging as it was 100% full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe. Modern batteries are not affected by long-term charging, especially only 17 hours. And you can't really harm your laptop by leaving it plugged in either (unless it gets struck by lightning, or something similar).

Comment: Is is that full charged LI-ion battery do not generate heat.

Comment: When a battery has reached full capacity, it stops charging. So it doesn't generate heat. However, if your laptop has overheating problems, I would put it on a stand while it's updating to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that too. I also charged my battery while having a my Windows 10 Update. It only took me 6 hours of updating. Before I tried updating my device, I just charge it to 100% and then restarted the pc.Sadly,it says that undoing changes to your computer. I tried it for two times and for the third time, the fist advice above did work and when I troubleshoot the battery, it fixes everything more clearly.But,I'm afraid you'll going to have to decide whether charge your laptop or not cause sometimes it also drains battery fast.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your laptop on charge when it updates anyway. I think it's a **requirement** and if it's not plugged in then it will not update. Whenever you have to restart to update, it tells you to plug in your laptop and restart. So yes, you should leave it on charge, it won't harm modern batteries.